# Is it theoretically possible to design a provably unhackable hardware/software system?

Tags: security, proof

Has there been any work done on any hypothetical hardware + OS architecture or overall software design which is provably not possible to hack? In other words, an architecture which allows for only limited code execution such that exploits are not at all feasible within some particular mathematical definition of an "exploit". Therefore the potential damage that exploits could do under this framework would be provably limited.

Generally speaking, I'm looking for a mathematically motivated theory of "hackable" versus "unhackable" architectures based on some reasonable underlying assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you restrict that to 'hacking' and leave all other security aspects aside (say, broadcasting sensitive information or whatever), you will find many answers at [LANGSEC](http://langsec.org). (Be sure to look at the [short intro](http://langsec.org/occupy).)

They offer a definition for hacking (*unexpected input-driven computation*), describe the theory behind the problems (turing complete file formats and protocols, ad-hoc parsing, differing grammars) and explain how to avoid that.  You just need to actually do this in your code.

---

(If you meant to include more general security aspects (undefined behavior, program crashes, access restrictions):  Yes, tons of stuff.  I can write a *loong* explanation, if you like.)

Comment: — I would love to hear more of your thoughts on the subject, particularly in the area of access restriction: I have been using some ideas from LANGSEC for an access control scheme.

Answer (score 3):

There have been attempts, but nothing that is practically useful. There is always the possibility of behavior that isn't captured in the mathematical formalism (side channel attacks for instance), and if that fails, the human operators are usually a big vulnerability.

In reality, nothing is ever 100% secure. The big question is whether the effort required to hack something is worth the potential payoffs.